# How to design a matrix $A$ that removes first $m$ elements of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the result is $\mathbb{R}^{n-m} \ni y = Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> How to design a matrix $A$ that removes first $m$ elements of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the result is $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$?

Example:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}^{10} \ni x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    2  \\
    \vdots \\
    10 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Now, I am looking for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 10}$ such that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}^{6} \ni y = A  x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    5  \\
    6  \\
    \vdots \\
    10 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Can anybody help me to design this matrix $A$? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the matrix. Here I post the answer if someone is interested.

\begin{align}
A =  
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{(n-m) \times m} & I_{(n-m)},   
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $0_{(n-m) \times m}$ is a zero matrix matrix of size $(n-m) \times m$ and $I_{(n-m)}$ is an identity matrix of size $(n-m) \times (n-m) $.